# Moving a test WP site to live

Tags: urls

I am new to WP and want to check something before I start down a patch that might not work.

Using WordPress can I easily change the site URL?

For example, I have an existing website visible at www.mysite.com.

I want to build a replacement site in WordPress, and while its being built I want it to appear at test.mysite.com. Once I've got everything set as I want and confirmed working I'd like to then have the same site replace the content of www.mysite.com.

Is that easily doable? I've read a few articles about changing the site url but it seems to be rather complex involving database updates and whatnot. I'd imagine this is a fairly common request.

Comment: You need to setup the subdomain test.mysite.com first. You can do it from the control panel section of your hosting service provider.

Comment: This is something that's been asked and answered many times here. A quick search will give you some very good and detailed solutions.

Comment: I had tried a search, but didn't hit on what I was looking for so apologies for any duplication.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily update the Site Url in WP, 
In the general settings of the Admin section (/wp-admin/options-general.php). Be sure the set the correct URL in the 'WordPress Address (URL)' and 'Site Address (URL)' fields.

You may want to check your config file (wp-config.php) too, if you need to switch databases while moving from Test to Live.